# How to poll a URL using the same InputStreamReader

Tags: java, inputstream

I have an URL that is being constantly updated with new data that i want to retrieve. I wrote this code to retrieve the content every 5 seconds, but the `reader` is null after one iteration.

```
InputStream is = new URL("someURL").openStream();
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
while (true){
    Info info = gson.fromJson(reader, Info.class);
    for (Update update : info.updates){
        if (update.type.equals("data")){
            System.out.println(update.toString());
        }
    }
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

Is it possible to somehow reset the `reader` and make it read updated data from the stream in the next iteration or do i have to create a new instance of `InputStreamReader` in each iteration?

Comment: sounds like some sort of message queue would be a better fix.

Comment: Regarding the given code, how should the `reader` be null? It's no re-assigned in your code.

Comment: The reader cannot possibly be null in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-create the input stream (i.e. 'is'). So you need to reopen the connection, again and again. And close it, if you like it to do it while(true).

I don't believe the reader is null, probable just reached EOS.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the docs for the Reader class, which InputStreamReader extends:

`/**
     * Resets the stream.  If the stream has been marked, then attempt to
     * reposition it at the mark.  If the stream has not been marked, then
     * attempt to reset it in some way appropriate to the particular stream,
     * for example by repositioning it to its starting point.  Not all
     * character-input streams support the reset() operation, and some support
     * reset() without supporting mark().
     *
     * @exception  IOException  If the stream has not been marked,
     *                          or if the mark has been invalidated,
     *                          or if the stream does not support reset(),
     *                          or if some other I/O error occurs
     */
    public void reset() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException("reset() not supported");
    }`

The InputStreamReader does not override the reset() method, so you will not be able to use it to reset the stream.  You will need to find a different implementation to accomplish what you're looking for.  Or you can just recreate the stream with every iteration.  Depending on performance concerns, this may not be an issue as long as you close open resources at the end of each iteration.

Hope this helps.